# How to add a new key value pair to each object in a PHP multi-dimensional array?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I need to map over an existing multi-dimensional array and conditionally add a new item to each array object.

If the original Array is :

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 4
        [uid] => 1
        [name] => Dave Spicer
        [content] => another post
        [post_date] => 2018-12-03 00:02:26
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 3
        [uid] => 2
        [name] => John Doe
        [content] => some post
        [post_date] => 2018-12-03 00:02:21
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [uid] => 1
        [name] => Dave Spicer
        [content] => My first post!
        [post_date] => 2018-12-02 23:21:07
    )

)
```

I'd like to loop through it, conditionally adding a new key value pair to each array object which would result in a new array like this :

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 4
        [uid] => 1
        [name] => Dave Spicer
        [content] => another post
        [post_date] => 2018-12-03 00:02:26
        [liked] => YES
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 3
        [uid] => 2
        [name] => John Doe
        [content] => some post
        [post_date] => 2018-12-03 00:02:21
        [liked] => NO
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [uid] => 1
        [name] => Dave Spicer
        [content] => My first post!
        [post_date] => 2018-12-02 23:21:07
        [liked] => YES
    )

)
```

I assume that I need to create a new array, and that it isn't possible to push into a existing multi-dimensional array - as that's what I've been trying to do to no avail - but I could be completely wrong there. Please let me know if that is the case.

I've tried copying the array and running a `foreach` loop on it but have only been able to add one new key value pair at the very end of all of the arrays as a new array object.

Could somebody point me in the direction of the correct function(s) to be using here please? `array_merge`? `array_combine`? `array_push`? etc

Comment: Why do you think you need to create a new array? `$array[$index]['liked'] = "NO";` will modify an element of an array.

Comment: Thanks @Barmar , yeah I just worked out that for myself. Came back to post the answer.

Comment: I realise that I don't need to create a new array now too, despite my comment on your answer below. Thanks for your help brother :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You add an element to an array simply by assigning to the index.

```
foreach ($array as $i => $element) {
    $array[$i]['liked'] = get_like($element);
}
```

You can also use a reference variable in the `foreach` loop:

```
foreach ($array as $i => &$element) {
    $element['liked'] = get_like($element);
}
```

Comment: That's way better than what I had just worked out which was : `$newArray = $postsArray; $i=0; foreach($newArray as $post) { $liked = getlikes($post['id'], $user_id); if ($liked) { $newArray[$i]['liked'] = true } else { $newArray[$i]['liked'] = false } $i++; } }`

Comment: I'm getting PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type WP_Term as array error.  

I had used:  $my_array[$i]['url'] = $img_url1;

Comment: Either `$my_array` or `$my_array[$i]` is not an array, it's a WordPress object of some kind. @KailashGajara

Comment: Thanks. Yes, its fixed now.